# On Apple M1, grpc/Google-Api Import Error:

Tags: python, google-api, grpc, arm64, apple-m1

**Situation:**

I'm trying to set up my SQLAlchemy database and run it locally. I use the google api for its vision module, so I can analyze text off of pictures.

Currently I had to switch from an old 2013 macbook to a new 2020 macbook with the m1 chip.  I try to run my local environment but receive the following error.

**ERROR:**

```
File "/Users/gabriel/Desktop/PROJECT_NAME/src/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import actions
  File "/Users/gabriel/Desktop/PROJECT_NAME/src/actions.py", line 3, in <module>
    import utils
  File "/Users/gabriel/Desktop/PROJECT_NAME/src/utils.py", line 5, in <module>
    import google.cloud.vision_v1 as vision
  File "/Users/gabriel/.local/share/virtualenvs/PROJECT_NAME/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/vision_v1/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .services.image_annotator import ImageAnnotatorClient as IacImageAnnotatorClient
  File "/Users/gabriel/.local/share/virtualenvs/PROJECT_NAME/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/vision_v1/services/image_annotator/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .client import ImageAnnotatorClient
  File "/Users/gabriel/.local/share/virtualenvs/PROJECT_NAME/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/vision_v1/services/image_annotator/client.py", line 25, in <module>
    from google.api_core import gapic_v1  # type: ignore
  File "/Users/gabriel/.local/share/virtualenvs/PROJECT_NAME/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from google.api_core.gapic_v1 import config
  File "/Users/gabriel/.local/share/virtualenvs/PROJECT_NAME/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/config.py", line 23, in <module>
    import grpc
  File "/Users/gabriel/.local/share/virtualenvs/PROJECT_NAME/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from grpc import _compression
  File "/Users/gabriel/.local/share/virtualenvs/PROJECT_NAME/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_compression.py", line 15, in <module>
    from grpc._cython import cygrpc
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/gabriel/.local/share/virtualenvs/PROJECT_NAME/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Users/gabriel/.local/share/virtualenvs/PROJECT_NAME/lib/python3.10/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.cpython-310-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/cygrpc.cpython-310-darwin.so' (no such file)
```

**Hypothesis:**

I believe it does have to do with trying to get the universal binary version in my dependencies, but at this point, I have no idea how link them correctly or if I even have the right package.

**Specs:**

- OS: Mac OS Monterey 12.0.1 (21A559)
- Computer: MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)
- IDE: VSCode

Dependencies:

- Python: "3.10.0"
- grpcio: "1.41.1"
- sqlalchemy: "1.4.26"

**Tried Solutions:**

- Ran without grpcio dependency, worked.
- Originally ran database on two non-m1 chip macbooks, did not have this error.
- Uninstalled and reinstalled grpcio without cache.
- Deleted my local environment and recreated it

Comment: hi Gabriel have you checked here ? https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/25082

Answer (score 7):

Run the following commands from within your shell (or from within your virtual environment)

```
pip install --no-binary :all: grpcio --ignore-installed
pip install --no-binary :all: grpcio-tools --ignore-installed
```

You can find more info from this [comment](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/28387#issuecomment-1054668742) made here for the [Github Issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/28387)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Update: The issue is fixed in `grpcio` 1.47.0 and newer.